# SelectedNodeChanged of ASP.Net Treeview not firing

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am new to Treeview.  I want to display the log files from my local directory in a treeview and clicking upon it, the file should open. Below is my code:

1) My aspx page:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvLogResults" runat="server" ExpandDepth="1" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvLogResults_SelectedNodeChanged" style="margin-left: 33px; margin-top: 16px;">
                        <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
                        <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px"
                            NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                            <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                            <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Styles/imgs/open-folder.jpg" />
                            <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                        </asp:TreeView>
```

2) Codebehind

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
        n.Value = "0";
        n.Text = "LogFiles-Datewise";
        n.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
        tvLogResults.Nodes.Add(n);


        string data = txtFromDate.Text;
        DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(data, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);

        DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text);

        string path = string.Concat(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, @"LogFiles");



        var files = from c in currDirectory.GetFiles()
                    where c.CreationTime >= fromDate && c.CreationTime <= toDate
                    select c;
        int i = 1;
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            DateTime lastAccessTime = file.LastAccessTime;
            TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
            child.Value = file.FullName;
            child.Text = lastAccessTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            child.PopulateOnDemand = true;
            child.NavigateUrl = file.FullName;
            child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
            tvLogResults.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(child);
            i++;
        }
    }

    protected void tvLogResults_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Server.MapPath(tvLogResults.SelectedValue);

        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filename);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file.FullName);
        }
    }
```

Even though while selecting the node, the fullpath is displayed as "file:\\C:\TraceFiles\Log11Nov.txt" (IE &Chrome), the file never opens. Nothing happens while clicking the node. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure a file path starting with `file:\\ ` is going to open using the local file system?  Have you tried without the `file:\\ `?

Comment: Also, just in case you're not aware, the ASP.NET is running on the server.  If the file you're trying to access is local on the computer running the browser, then you will not be able to load it... instead you'd have to allow the user to select the file manually and upload it for processing

Answer (score 0):

Those are not valid urls to local files.

Refer: [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

> For a network location:
>
> file://hostname/path/to/the%20file.txt
>
> Or for a local file, the hostname is omitted, but the slash is not
>   (note the third slash):
>
> file:///c:/path/to/the%20file.txt

Hope that fixes it for you.

Comment: My gut feeling is a misunderstanding of file locations (client and server) as per my comment under the OP

Comment: Yes, it would be better to serve the files via IIS, rather than open them locally on the machine. But then we don't know what case the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: I was wrong earlier. Sorry for that, The fullpath is displayed as file:///C:/TraceFiles/LogFiles/Log11Nov.txt" only. Even I have changed to different drive and different location, still nothing happens. The event 'OnSelectedNodeChanged' event is not firing at all. Is there any other event to be added while clicking the node?

Comment: Are you binding the tree everytime on page load?

Comment: In order to read from different location, I put the files manually inside the application folder,then also nothing happens.I then published to IIS and tried, no results. The url, "file:///C:/TraceFiles/LogFiles/Log11Nov.txt" is displaying when mouse over the child node, but not opening the file.

Comment: @ nunespascal - No. The binding happens only on Search button click. Functionality is user chooses the date (from date and to date, then provide any search string , and click on Search button), only then treeview node populates. That is the code first written for btnSearch_Click.